# Entry alert needs to trigger only after 5 minute candle close

Tags: pine-script

This is a trading view pine script only question.

So I've been trying to set an ***entry alert*** for an opening range breakout.

However, I need the alert to be fired only on the close of the **5 min candle** and not on the latest close of the breakout (which happens as soon as the price crosses the range). Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Basically, what should the long or short condition look like?

My entry condition right now is

```
long = close > RangeHigh
short = close < RangeLow
```

But I need it to be the full close of the 5 min candle.

Comment: The answer will depend on the resolution of the chart you are running the code on.

Comment: I'll always be running the code on 5 minutes timeframe. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can control the behavior you want from the "Create Alert" db in the chart UI. Select "Once Per Bar Close" for the trigger option when you create the alert; it will only fire when the realtime bar closes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PineCoders-LucF 
This did work, my parameters needed to be changed. So instead of 
close > RangeHigh
it was supposed to be crossover(close, RangeHigh)

Comment: Good idea! Will trigger less often )